# need to put 2 dll file in system32 pyinstaller

Tags: python, dll, project, pyinstaller, system32

I've writing project with python 2.7 and i need to put my two dll files in system32 folder . 
is possible to load dll file to my exe project(create with pyinstaller) and extract it to system32 folder  when run program?

Comment: Why do you think you need to put the two DLLs in C:\Windows\system32?  This to me seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Would it be enough to have the DLLs available for your scripts? Would data_files option be enough for you?

Comment: i need to put two external dll's to system 32

Comment: You haven't answered my query.  **Why** do you need to put those two DLLs in C:\Windows\system32?

Comment: my dlls are : xvidvfw.dll and xvidcore.dll which are XIVD codec dll . i've used XVID in my python opencv project and opencv load they dll from system32 .

Comment: @ahmadasaad were you able to get this done? In a similar situation